# Flag weight in profile page

Tags: discussion, profile-page

Some users have a flag weight in their profile and others don't. How is it calculated and what does it mean? I could not find anything searching meta.

Comment: When you get to 10,000 rep you get to see the flagged posts in the area next to 'tools' - have approved most (mainly spelling and approving posts by users with insufficient privileges). does take up more of your time. @underdark Good luck in the elections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with flagging posts, and those with a higher weight get higher priority for moderator attention when they do flag a post. Check out the [SO blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/) talking about it.

Comment: higher flag weight also means you get more flags to cast

Comment: I've been able to rack up a healthy flag weight simply by flagging questions where the author has expressed interest in having it CW, and commenting "please make this community wiki".  People can't designate their own question as CW - it can only be done by a moderator.  I kinda feel guilty about benefiting from this layer of bureaucracy.